# Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT app crash when using pivot

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

In my project, whenever I try to add PivotItem to Pivot element it crashes the app with error:

```
+       [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException]   {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IVector`1.Append(T value)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.VectorToCollectionAdapter.Add[T](T item)
   at testProj.MainPage.<OnNavigatedTo>d__3.MoveNext()} System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

It happens when I declare Pivot in XAML like:

```
<Pivot>
        <PivotItem>

        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

It happens when I try to add PivotItem in code-behind and when I create Pivot entirely in code-behind.
Cleaning and rebuilding solution didn't help.

edit:
Xaml file:

```
<Page
x:Class="testProj.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:testProj"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">


    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Pivot>
            <PivotItem>

            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Phone.UI.Input;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace testProj
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your full xaml cade and also .cs code..

Comment: edit the question to include xaml and .cs code

Comment: please let us know your platfrom :- windows phone 8 or windows phone 8.1(silver light) or windows phone 8.1(windows run time) .. i think you messing up here

Comment: It's a Universal App, targeting Windows Phone 8.1 run time

Comment: <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5 0">
            <Pivot SelectedIndex="0">
                <PivotItem Header="Header1">
                    <local:HeaderPage />
                </PivotItem>

Comment: update your environment vs updates , it is not coming in my side, it would be better to try in new projects,